# Google cloud Loadbalancing not gzip css

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have a system use HTTP(S) load balancer of google cloud. I have a problem about gizp with static file. On each web server, I config enable gzip as bellow code:

```
gzip             on;
gzip_comp_level  2;
gzip_min_length  1000;
gzip_proxied     any; # expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/xml image/svg+xml;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
```

then I access home page, the gzip applied, but I access css file, gzip does not apply. Everything I see when I access css page is:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
alt-svc:clear
cache-control:max-age=31536000
content-length:614170
content-type:text/css
date:Sat, 22 Jul 2017 04:14:08 GMT
etag:"5967cbd7-95f1a"
expires:Sun, 22 Jul 2018 04:14:08 GMT
last-modified:Thu, 13 Jul 2017 19:36:55 GMT
server:nginx
status:200
via:1.1 google
x-host:instance2
```

Please help me find a reason and how to fix. Thanks